# How to update multiple Models in single action? (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 models and I have a very important reason to update all models (maybe in separate actions but in 1 action, if possible).

If I want to update 1 model I can use

```
def update
  @modelA = ModelA.find(params[:id]
  respond_to do |format|
      if @modelA.update(modelA_params)
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "" }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.json { render json: @modelA.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { render :show }
      end
    end
end
```

with appropriate params. How would I change this if I have Configuration page and I want to update 4 models (separately of course)? I have 4 columns for each model and I want to update each column the appropriate attribute from model. In my case, I am using the [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) gem to update attributes.

> The question is...there is any hack for that? like batch update with
>   case condition or should i create update action for every model to
>   update them?(in configuration_controller)

Comment: Of course you can collect different params belonging to different models in the same form. And then update 4 different models within a single controller action (#create or #update). It's no special hack, it is an ability to a controller to call any record from any model .. You can use nested forms. Or just collect with no disctinction, and then assign manually within the controller action.

Comment: Depending on if these models are related, you may be able to use [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Hi am facing a similar, my models are not related but i wish to update them wiyh a single action, could you please say how you resolved yours? @Skrpter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can pass the parameters for all 4 models to the action, you could do something like:

```
# app/controllers/configuration_controller.rb
def update
  @a = ModelA.find(params[:model_a][:id])
  @b = ModelB.find(params[:model_b][:id])
  @c = ModelC.find(params[:model_c][:id])
  @d = ModelD.find(params[:model_d][:id])

  @a.assign_attributes(model_a_params)
  @b.assign_attributes(model_b_params)
  @c.assign_attributes(model_c_params)
  @d.assign_attributes(model_d_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @a.save && @b.save && @c.save && @d.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.json { render json: [@a.errors, @b.errors, @c.errors, @d.errors], status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.html { render :show }
    end
  end

  private

  def model_a_params
  params.require(:model_a).permit(:id) # and other permitted params
end

#... same for the other 3 models
```

I have used `assign_attributes` here, as you may want [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) in the action.

**[EDIT]**

If, on the other hand, you want to update the models in separate actions, then simply have 4 separate actions in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/configuration_controller.rb
def update_model_a
  @a = ModelA.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @a.save
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.json { render json: [@a.errors, @b.errors, @c.errors, @d.errors], status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.html { render :show }
    end
  end

  def update_model_b
    @b = ModelB.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @b.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "" }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.json { render json: [@a.errors, @b.errors, @c.errors, @d.errors], status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { render :show }
      end
    end

# ... etc.

private

def model_a_params
  params.require(:model_a).permit(:id) # and other permitted params
end

def model_b_params
  params.require(:model_b).permit(:id) # and other permitted params
end

# ... etc.

#... same for the other 3 models
```

Comment: hmmm your solution is interesting...but i was trying to implement and there i found few issues... I forgot to tell you that x-editable take 1 attribute from appropriate model and call to controller to request update, so if i want to update attributute from modelA it responds " I have not found modelB obiect :id, modelC obiect :id etc...so i dont want to "Sift the whole bag" with all models but i want to make action which take single attribute from appropriate model and update it.

Comment: and my response from binding.pry when i want to update: 
[1] pry(#<ConfigurationsController>)> params
=> {"modelA"=>{"name"=>"someNameToUpdate"}, "controller"=>"configurations", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"12"}

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question.  I am also not familiar with the gem you're using.  If you can change the `action` in your above parameters to, say `update_model_a`, then you could have one call per individual model.  So you would need 4 update actions in the `ConfigurationsController`, one for each model.

Comment: @Skrypter, for the sake of clarity for other people looking at this question, did the answer above help?  Or was it the comment?

Comment: The answer found in the comment...Thats why i said ty for help...and for other people: "If you have problem like i had you should consider your situation...if you going to update few models in 1 controller and to this  controller coming just 1 attribute from single model then you should have 1 action per update every model...BUT if you using FORM and there you put attributes from few models then you should create 1 action to handle update for few models in the same time".